# If and how can I add a variable and use it in commands?

Tags: environment-variables

How do I define a variable that can be used in commands? If it is even possible?

I want to assign a length to a variable and use it in \addvspace, like:

```
\newcommand{\xxx}{1em}
\addvspace{\xxx}
```

Or:

```
\newlength{\xxx}
\setlength{\xxx}{1em}
\addvspace{\xxx}
```

But it doesn't work. Since there is no way to add automatic vertical space in paragraphs (without messing up everything, like \parskip), I thought it would be nice to have a variable then so all spaces can be adjusted without changing 5000 hardcoded spaces in the document each time.

Comment: I added an answer, but it sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171556) ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show an example of your usage of `\addvspace`? I believe you're misusing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a length register:

```
\newlength{\xxx}
\setlength{\xxx}{1em}
\vspace{\xxx}, \addvspace{\xxx}, \rule{\xxx}{\xxx}
```

I.e. `\xxx` can be used everywhere where a length value is expected.

Unfortunately when using relative units, they are converted to an absolute value according to the active font settings, when calling `\setlength`.

But if you want to have a par skip, wha don’t you set `\parskip`, or better use the `parskip` package (or `parskip` option in KOMA-SCript)?

Comment: Because parskip adds space everywhere, everywhere. Could wrap all text clumps in \\parskip to avoid it, but the same problem would emerge. Still need a variable to define them all. But ok, so \\addvspace doesn't work but \\vspace does. Seems logic

Comment: No … \addvspace should work too. The difference ist that you use a length instead of a macro ;-)

Comment: @K.C.: If my answer answers you question, pleas mark it as accepted ;-) otherwise, what is missing?